# Is there anything that would cause MonoTouch to not generate crash reports?

Tags: xamarin.ios

Is there anything that would cause MonoTouch to not generate crash reports when the app crashes or should it always generate one without fail? ('cause mine is failing)

In my project I hard coded it to throw a NullRefException on a certain action. I would expect to see a crash report written to the Device Logs in XCode but I am not seeing any report generated.

The Console outputs a managed stack trace of where the exception is being thrown though.

You might be wondering why I would want a crash report if I can see it in the console? Well, I want to make sure that crash reports are being generated on test devices and on production builds.

**Update:** I noticed that upgrading MT from 3.2.6 to 4.0.1 will allow my app to generate crash reports. Unfortunately we're having instability issues with our app running on 4.0.1. Why would 3.2.6 be any different when it comes to crash reporting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some reason upgrading to MonoTouch 5 fixed this.

Answer (score 0):

Do you happen to have a top-level exception handler in your "Main" method ?

Something like below?  That would keep you from getting a crash report, since it is a clean exit as far as iOS is concerned.

```
static void Main (string[] args)
        {
         try {
            UIApplication.Main (args);
         } catch (Exception e){
            Log.ErrorFormat ("Toplevel exception: {0}", e);
         }
        }
```

Comment: No. I do not have a try catch in the Main(). The console just shows the managed stack trace and states that it exited with error code 1. I would assume that code 1 means that it didn't exit cleanly. Could be wrong.